# export to PDF in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, export-to-pdf

I want to export all the components from a web page into a PDF file. Each component on the web page (including chart, report, grids) should appear on separate page of the PDF file.
Is there any plugin available to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres a very good [Plugin](https://www.apexofficeprint.com/index.html), but it's not free.

Comment: Technically, it does have a free plan :)

Comment: Thanks @DanMcGhan didn't knew :)